# PySpark HashingTF Count of Documents which have a given term

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, tf-idf

I have a spark data-frame in which the column "text" has some text. I want to count the number of rows in which the various words occur - essentially the number of "documents" in which a "term" occurs - and the related counts like the most frequent word, the rows (or call it documents) which have this most frequent word.

I'm making use of HashingTF from pyspark.ml.feature. But can't seem to find an efficient way to extract this information from the output.

```
# As an example create a Pandas-df
import pandas as pd
pandas_df = pd.DataFrame({"text": ["The cat jumped over the lazy dog",
                                   "The dog jumped and jumped and ran after the bird"
                                  ]}) 

# Convert to Spark-df
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)

# Add a column which has the individual words
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, col
spark_df = spark_df.withColumn("words", split(col("text"), " "))

# Use HashingTF
from pyspark.ml.feature import HashingTF
hashingTF = HashingTF(inputCol="words", outputCol="features")

df_term_frequency = hashingTF.transform(spark_df)
```

As an example for the first row, the data-frame "df_term_frequency" column "features" has:

vectorType: "sparse"

length: 262144

indices: [1398, 51504, 54556, 95889, 141363, 179832, 201496]

values: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

This columns would have the term-frequencies. How can get the total number of rows (documents) which have the word "lazy"; number of rows (documents) which have the word "dog" and "bird"?

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easier way was to use .rlike